# Reasonable ways to ask for possible approaches to a problem

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Many questions that seek (legitimately in my opinion) to ask "what are my options for solving this problem?" seem to me to be almost summarily closed on SE sites without thought to how difficult it is to wade through endless jargon and acronyms and make any reasonable evaluation of possible ways to approach a problem in an unfamiliar domain.

Case in point: I suddenly need "networking" options for the redevelopment of an existing "real-time" system. After two days of internet searches, I feel barely any closer to identifying anything that I am certain can help me. I would really like to ask a real person (not a search engine) what technologies I should be considering, but I don't like my chances of asking for that on Programmers or StackOverflow and getting anything other than a closed question.

So... is there a constructive way to ask such questions... on an SE site?

Side-thought: the newest coolest stuff emerges in the zone between the known and the unknown, where matters of fact have not yet taken root, where opinion is divided, and where possibility is the flavour of the day. That zone might look like the wild west to some, but why does SE seem so unwilling to to have a presence in that zone? Frankly I think they're just inviting some cooler Q&A site to emerge and steal their entire market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to frame your problem as a question with a narrow focus, and written for the correct audience.

The problem you are facing is that you aren't sure which experts you need and you don't seem to know enough about the problem you face to explain it clearly.

Throwing out a poorly defined problem to a group of people who may or may not be able to solve it for you simply doesn't work with the specific type of Q&A Stack Exchange focuses on. You will have to do more research yourself before you can understand the audience you should be asking, and how to ask.

The simplest thing to do, though, is start calling up companies that specialize in solving that problem.  Even if you ultimately decide to solve it in-house, you will likely receive a lot of good feedback on the problem itself and how to approach it.

Comment: Thanks - that's constructive. I believe I know who to ask and can describe the problem very clearly and precisely... but that makes it detailed, and subject to "TL;DR" and/or summary closure. I've never managed to walk the line between too vague and too detailed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is putting the cart before the horse.  The SE network isn't here to give you ideas about how to do stuff.  It's here to help you through the options you decide on.

There's nothing more subjective than ideas.  Everyone has their own method of getting things done, and that's exactly what you'd get as answers.  It's as opinion-based as you can get, and there's no single right way to solve a problem.  Is there a best way?  Doubtful.  Every system has it's own quirks and ways it likes to do things.  There's a *best practice*, and you might be able to get an objective answer to that question, but the capability to implement best practice is iffy at the best of times.

If you want to talk to a real person about what your options are, that's what a contractor is for.  Remember, the people who help you here are doing it for *free*.